# Should users be a resource in Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-routing

In a Laravel application with user authentication, should the users be a resource?

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

And if so, what would be a proper way to handle authentication? Adding login and logout methods to the UsersController?

Right now I have the following routes that handle the registration and authentication process

```
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', function () {
    return View::make('login');
}]);

Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');

Route::get('/register', ['as' => 'register', function () {
    return View::make('register');
}]);

Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
```

It seems logical to move the users to a resource route and maybe create some custom actions. How would you handle this, and what is the best practices?

Comment: If the application is small enough, then yes, create a resource controller for User to handle CRUD.  For authentication, just add auth to the "before": http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to determine what should be a Resource**

When determining what should be a resource I usually refer to my database model.  You can create a DB model in [DIA](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia) or an equivalent. If you have a good understanding of Entity Relationships you should have no problems determining what should or should not be a resource.

[image: ER Diagram]

Take a look at the diagram above...this is an ER Diagram.  Create one of these before you start coding any project.  You wouldn't build a house without a foundation...it helps a ton when starting any DB Driven application.

The blue squares are entities (tables), the yellow ovals are attributes (columns in the table), and the red diamonds are relationships.

90% of the time your entities (tables) should be resources and have models associated with them.  Then define your relationships in your model for Eloquent ORM.  Now you have everything perfectly laid out for you.  A resource is anything that needs to have CRUD abilities and usually that applies to your entities (tables).  Since users is an entity...yes absolutely it should be a resource and have it's own model in your project.

Comment: wow this is awesome @Rafael. I am going to book mark this. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Rafeal. I am familiar with entity/relation diagram, but haven't thought about resources in this context. Thanks.